# Control the action sheet displayed while long pressing the url in text view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a textview which has properties-- > SELECTABLE:YES and EDITABLE:NO.
For opening a url written in textview, I made use of

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView )textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL )URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
```

delegate method of textview which seems to be working fine.

The problem is when a user long press the link in textview, an action sheet pops up which is the default behaviour. I want to control that action sheet.

Please suggest ways.

[image]

Have tried using ActionSheet delegate but it didn't worked.

Comment: What do you want to control in the `actionsheet`?

Comment: If you're happy to use a 3rd party library [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) has got a lot to offer. I've been using it in various projects to insert 'hyperlinks' in text blocs without having to display the actual URL (a bit equivalent to `<a href="">` tags in HTML).

Comment: If you are using some additional library name it

Comment: if you do not want open action sheet then return no in delegate method

Comment: @iPeter I want to call a function if a user clicks on copy option in the actionsheet.

Comment: @Anilsolanki I cant return no because the link will not open then.

Comment: @AbdulKarim I am not using any third party library.

Comment: @ved can you share some more code for reference..

Comment: - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView )textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL )URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
   // API Call here

 [self apiCall];
    
    return YES;
// Configure the view for the selected state
}   @AbdulKarim

Comment: You could always add your own `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and open your own action sheet who's delegate methods you can handle!

Comment: Before returning save the url in object and open it in webview

Answer (score 1):

**Swift4**

Simply return `false` in `-shouldInteractWith` but you have to handle the interaction yourself if you need any.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool 
{    
    print(String(format: "%@", URL as CVarArg))

    let alerSheet = UIAlertController.init(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alerSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Copy", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        print("copy action")
    }))

    alerSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Other", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        print("other action")
    }))

    alerSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action) in
        print("cancel action")
    }))
    self.present(alerSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

    return false
}
```